# What is the default frame rate in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I know that the Node's update method will be called every frame if we call scheduleUpdate for the current node. Is the delta parameter in the update method the same on all devices and platforms? If not, then how can I calculate what the frame rate or the delta value is on the device running my game?

Answer (score 0):

I the AppDelegate you will see a line like below:

```
director->setDisplayStats(true);
```

If the value passed down is set to true you will see the frame rate of your game in the bottom left corner. You can follow that code to see how they calculate the FPS, if you want to add constant frame rate functionality to your code.

[EDIT: Based on the comment below]
The way I have done what you want in the past is by having a dedicated game controller which has a scheduled update function and I use that to set a delta value that can be passed around or accessed by other components of the game.

Comment: What I really want is a way to get frame rate programmatically at runtime and outside of the update method.

Comment: @congtrungvnit Read the edit above. Could you maybe explain why you want this value outside of the update loop? It wouldn't be much use outside of that function. Add what you want to accomplish to your question description above.

Comment: Yeah, that is because I want to make a infinite running game and I want to calculate how height and far my character can reach when jump.My code is like this:

Comment: if ( true == isFalling )
    {
        character->setPositionX( visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x );
        character->setPositionY( character->getPositionY() - ( FALLING_SPEED * visibleSize.height ) );
    }
    else
    {
        character->setPositionX( visibleSize.width / 2 + origin.x );
        character->setPositionY( character->getPositionY() + ( FALLING_SPEED * visibleSize.height ) );
    }

This code is called in the update method to make the character jump. The isFalling variable is changed after INTERVAL seconds and terrain is moving with TERRAIN speed.

Comment: @congtrungvnit still don't know why you would need the delta outside of the update function. What I usually do to get the functionality you want is make my character a box2d physicsBody and call apply Linear impulse to it (only giving impulse in the y-direction). This way you don't have to manage is falling, or collisions or any of those things. As long as the rest of the world is constructed of physics bodies all the collision and "jumping" should be taken care of. I suggest you use existing libs to do things like this, it's been tried and tested by thousands of devs. It works :)

Comment: Hmmm... you means something like characterPhysicsBody->applyImpulse( Vect( character->getPositionX(), MAX_JUMP_HEIGHT ) )? If I do this, then how can I know how far my terrain moved when my character land the ground? I need to calculate this value because I want to calculate max gap between two blocks of my terrain. Thank you.

Comment: Ah and btw, what is the value you are often used for gravity of physic world in this case?

Comment: I usually set my gravity to -8.0, but it depends on what kind of physics reaction you want. You can modify your behaviour not only through gravity, but also using the bodyDef properties like density, mass, friction, etc... Also when applying the impulse you should set the x part as 0, otherwise the impulse will move your character forward at variable amounts depending on its X-value in the world. Which would be a bit weird. In all my infinite running games I never had to get the max distance for platforms, I know why you want to do it, but I don't think it's needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94174/discussion-between-congtrungvnit-and-dane-mackier).